# Modelica: Creation of Simple Fluid Models

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to create a modular simulation of flow components (at first without using the standard Modelica.Fluid, for learning and simplicity). I have decided to start with only worrying about mass flow (not temperature/enthalpy) and have created a connector `Stream` shown below:

```
connector Stream
  Real pressure;
  flow Real m_flow;
end Stream;
```

Using this connector, I want to track pressure and flow throughout a simple system:

```
flow source >> valve >> tank >> pump >> flow sink
```

I have created the following models for these components:

```
model FlowSource "Flow Source can be used as a starting point of a flow"
  parameter Real pressure = 1.0 "Pressure of the source";
  Stream outlet;
equation
  outlet.pressure = pressure;
end FlowSource;

model Valve
  parameter Real Cv "Valve Coefficient, Cv";
  Real setpoint(min=0,max=1) "Valve setpoint";
  Real dp(start=1) "Pressure drop across the valve";
  Real m(start=Cv) "Flow through the valve";
  Real f(min=0,max=1) "Valve Characteristic f(setpoint)";
  Stream inlet, outlet;
equation
  inlet.m_flow + outlet.m_flow= 0.0;  // Conservation of mass
  dp = inlet.pressure - outlet.pressure;  // Pressure drop calculation
  f = setpoint; // linear valve
  m = inlet.m_flow;
  m = if(dp >= 0) then Cv*f*sqrt(dp) else -Cv*f*sqrt(-dp);
end Valve;

model Tank "Simple model of a tank"
  parameter Real volume=1 "tank volume (m^3)";
  parameter Integer num_ports=1 "Number of ports";
  parameter Real static_pressure=1 "Internal Tank Pressure";
  parameter Real initial_level = 0;
  Stream[num_ports] ports "Stream Connectors";
  Real level "Level in % 0-100";
  protected
  Real vol "Volume of medium in the tank";  
initial equation
  level = initial_level;
equation
  for i in 1:num_ports loop
    ports[i].pressure = static_pressure;
  end for;
  der(vol) = sum(ports.m_flow); // need to add density conversion
  level = vol * 100 / volume;
end Tank;

model Pump "Simple model of a Pump"
  Real setpoint(min=0,max=1) "setpoint of the pump (0.0 to 1.0)";
  Stream inlet, outlet;
  protected
    Real dp "Pressure differential across the pump";
    Real f "flow rate inside pump";
equation
  inlet.m_flow+ outlet.m_flow= 0.0;
  dp = outlet.pressure - inlet.pressure;
  f = inlet.m_flow;
  dp = (100-400*(f^2)); // insert better pump char. curve here
end Pump;

model FlowSource "Flow Source can be used as a starting point of a flow"
  parameter Real pressure = 1.0 "Pressure of the source";
  Stream outlet;
equation
  outlet.pressure = pressure;
end FlowSource;
```

I can create instances of these models and connect them together in a separate model. However I am running into an issue of what I think is boundary conditions. I would like to specify the pressure of the incoming fluid source. The valve will then have a pressure drop across it as the flow moves to the tank. This is determined by the difference between the nominal pressure inside the tank and the fluid source, and should work ok.

The issue is when the pump meets the fluid sink (or if I had a pump going directly into a tank). Setting the pressure of the fluid sink causes problems with my pump because it also sets the pressure of the pump outlet (they are connected). The pressure of the pump needs to be a function of the inlet pressure and flow rate (it should add some pressure to the system), and the sink's pressure should be calculated based on this. However that pressure is also needed in the calculation for dp... so I end up in a circle.

What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to implement a system like this?

Thanks!

Edit:
I forgot to mention that the setpoints (pump does not yet implement it) are set in the main model that uses these models with an equation. So all of my models are balanced. (See my comment on the answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first advice is to "unit test" each of your component. Already at that point you will see that both the pump and the valve model have one variable too may (or are missing one equation). 
If you want to unit test your tank model you should make a model of a mass flow source (the one you call `FlowSource` is actually a pressure source) and connect two of them to your tank.

In the valve model you should make `setpoint` a parameter or an external input. In the pump model the variable `setpoint` is not used, so you can either delete it or make it a parameter.

Once you have fixed that you model works fine.

I put the fixes in an mo file that you can grab here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ojPn4YxnI9blRodUVWUjVGTE0/view?usp=sharing

Regards,
Rene Just Nielsen

Comment: Sorry I left out that I was setting the setpoints with an equation in the main model that I did not show here (I am using an external C function to provide an interface to dynamically change the setpoints). So that is not the problem with the model. The main issue is in regards to if I use a mass flow source (instead of pressure) it will set the flow through my valve (no matter what I set the valve to). And if I use pressure sources for a sink at the end, it sets the pressure at the end of my pump (which does not work for my pump's dp equation)

Comment: I guess part of the problem is that I could just add a resistance (a pipe) between the pump and the ending source, or the valve and the tank, etc... However I do not want the end user of these models to have to specify all of the pipe parameters just to do some simple tests of automation code (I just want to dynamically have the tank fill and drain etc...)

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to reproduce the problem you describe with your models. 

However, if you implement a more realistic pump curve in which you set the pump power or speed as a boundary condition the pump flow/pressure difference will adapt to whatever it is connected to.

For instance a simple relation between speed, pressure and flow could be:

"dp = dp_max((N/N_max)^2 - abs(dp/dp_max)*(dp/dp_max))".

The abs() operator will help you get the right flow direction.

I've updated the link in my answer above and added the pump curve.

Regards,
Rene Just Nielsen

Comment: If I follow you correctly: you want a boundary component that neither fixes pressure nor flow rate. 
If you try to make such a component with you Stream connector it will be unbalanced, i.e. it will have two variables (flow + pressure) and only one equation (the one that automatically sums all flow variables to zero).
Also, the flow through a real pump does depend on the downstream pressure, so eventually you will need to set the pressure somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I better understand what errors I was making now. Your implementation of the pump curve helps with some of the issues I was having, and I know I can structure my simulations different to avoid the desire to have a boundary component like you mentioned above.